# Entity references for \n and \t

Tags: html, xml

Do we have entity references for `\n` and `\t`?

My string is in xml format I have to split based on the tags and render as html so I need to add entity reference for \n and \t.
I need any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only five predefined entities in XML: `quot`, `amp`, `apos`, `lt` and `gt`. Tab and newline characters do not have a named entity reference on its own.

However, you can just use the Unicode code point:

```
&#0009;
&#0010;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use `\\t` and `\\n` to print as it is.